# Why label does not fit inside tableviewcell?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, autolayout, uikit, snapkit

I am using SnapKit for autolaoyut.
This is my view:

```
private func makeIconUI() {
    contentView.addSubview(iconView)
    iconView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(Dimesion.sidePadding)
        make.height.width.equalTo(19)
        make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(24)
    }
}

private func makeNumberUI() {
    contentView.addSubview(numberLabel)
    numberLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
    numberLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalTo(iconView.snp.trailing)
        make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(24)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
}

private func makeTitleUI() {
    contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalTo(numberLabel.snp.trailing)
        make.trailing.equalTo(self.snp.trailing)
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
```

The problem is:
Yellow label does not fit fully. The second label pushing on it, but I can fix it.

[image]

Comment: Try setting the Content Compression Resistance Priority: `numberLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am confused.Yellow doesn't fit fully like top of both labels dont match? then remove inset

```
    private func makeNumberUI() {
        contentView.addSubview(numberLabel)
        numberLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        numberLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.leading.equalTo(iconView.snp.trailing)
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
```

if logic is horizontally then give it a width like:

```
        view.addSubview(numberLabel)
        numberLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        numberLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.leading.equalTo(iconView.snp.trailing)
            make.width.equalTo(30)
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
```